# How to align TextView in android

Tags: android

I am adding `Linearlayout` dynamically and adding 3 `TextView` getting the content from `webservices` for text view if the content of 3 text size is larger it will display in the end of next line .i want display in start line how can i do?

Thanks

Comment: The specific answer at the end of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView   header_text;
header_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_text1);   
header_text.setSingleLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use android:gravity="left" or alignParent="left"

Answer (score 0):

To align your Text inside a specific TextView:

```
    Textview t = (Textview) findViewbyid(R.id.yourView); //refernce to your View
    t.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); //or any align you want
    t.setText("String text or long string");
```